# Integral of two lists doesn't give expected results

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to get the area under the curve which is defined by two lists (representing x and y coordinates). I am using the integrate function from scipy.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

x= np.array([0, 207.0, 52215.0])
y= np.array([0, 1367.0, 1461.0])

integrate.simps(y, x)
# Formated result
# 3 038 124 753.3677135
```

My problem is that when I do the math by hand, I get a different value, which is the same value I get when I do the integral of the previous list in two steps like the following example.

```
# Basically integral of [1367.0, 1461.0] over [207.0, 52215.0] 
#     plus integral of [0, 1367.0] over [0, 207.0], which should give same result as above
integrate.simps(y[1:],x[1:]) + integrate.simps(y[:2],x[:2]) 
# 73 680 796.5
```

This is the result I am looking for. What am I missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [numpy.trapz](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html):

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 207.0, 52215.0])
y = np.array([0, 1367.0, 1461.0])

np.trapz(y,x)
73680796.5
```

The trapezoidal rule is the simplest of numerical integration methods to estimate a definite integral: it approximates the curve with straight lines.

On the other hand Simpson's rule, implemented in [scipy.integrate.simps](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html), uses quadratic approximation for the function segments, each of which segment requires three points, sampled from your function.

Another answer regarding the difference between the two is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915116/how-to-decide-between-scipy-integrate-simps-or-numpy-trapz)